# why my HTML string doesn't show the correct html tag in WebView iOS?

Tags: ios, wkwebview

so I have this string that has html tag :

```
> "<h3>Kebijakan Privasi</h3>\r\n<h4>Pengumpulan Informasi
> Pribadi</h4>\r\n<p>Di MLI, Kami memahami bahwa hal privasi adalah hal
> yang penting. Kebijakan Privasi ini berlaku untuk seluruh produk,
> layanan dan informasi yang ditawarkan di dalam Platform MLI.
```

here is the full HTML [string](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vnleaq30ormbhmh/htmlstring.txt?dl=0) I have:

as you can see, the sentence "Kebijakan Privasi" has < h3 > element
and senctence "Pengumpulan Informasi Pribadi" has < h4 > element

so I expect the size of "Kebijakan Privasi" (h3) is bigger than  ""Pengumpulan Informasi Pribadi" (h4)

but here is the result when I run the app:

[image]

as you can see, "Kebijakan Privasi" seems smaller than "Pengumpulan Informasi Pribadi", I expect the other way around.

the HTML string that I have doesn't have the boilerplate HTML tag, I mean like

> < ! DOCTYPE HTML > , < head >, and < body >

Just like the string I share at the top. does it give effect? because if I see video tutorial from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7xWbwk9hLA), it seems it needs the boilerplate HTML tag

here is the simplified code I use, I am using **WKWebView** class:

```
class PageContentVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    var contentStringHTML = "some string with html tag in here"



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.loadHTMLString(contentStringHTML, baseURL: nil)                
    }        
}

extension PageContentVC : WKNavigationDelegate {

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        webView.isHidden = false
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }

}
```

so how to fix this? maybe you have a better solution for me.

Comment: Some tag of `html` doesn't work in iOS. So You have to apply different method for adjust font size. @Alexa289

Comment: @KomalGoyani what kind of method ? I don't have other idea for this

Comment: You have to change html code. You can replace not working html tags with working html tags. Like, You can add `font-size: \(size)pt` property instead of `<h3>` tag.

Comment: the html string that I have doesn't have the boiler plate html tag, I mean like < ! DOCTYPE html > , < head >, and < body >. just like the string I share at the top. does it give effect ? because if I see video tutorial from here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7xWbwk9hLA , it seems it needs the boilerplate html tag

Comment: Could you give me your full html code? I want to check that.

Comment: @KomalGoyani here is the full html string I have https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iXYM9pS2XxvTwKv8sdc60doIMryGcbUA . thanks in advance :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201188/discussion-between-komal-goyani-and-alexa289).

Comment: @KomalGoyani I finally find the answer :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the answer. I am not a web developer, so it seems that you also have to add the css script into the html string, like this

```
var someHTMLString = """

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Content Page</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.75">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
\(yourcontentHTMLStringHere)
</body>

</html>

"""
```

and then load it to WKWebView:

```
webView.loadHTMLString(someHTMLString, baseURL: nil)
```